# FloathMath error in my project

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development, this is my error

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: please take a look to my picture

Comment: Please don't put images in questions. Add the error text to the question and include your code as well.

Comment: Maybe it's `Math.sin()`?

Comment: Ok sir, its a new information for me, thank you!

Comment: Moreover, this question is not specific to Android Studio, so please stop re-tagging it with `android-studio`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Math.sin` instead of `FlatMath.sin`. From the doc

> Math routines similar to those found in Math.
>
> All methods were removed from the public API in version 23.

you can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/FloatMath.html)